# NodeRED make CTRL+S cause "Done" button click

Tags: node-red

I'm looking for some setting/mode/plugin so that when I click <kbd>CTRL+S</kbd> in NodeRED, after editing a function node, I don't get the system save dialog, but rather the "Done" button is clicked.

I can imagine a custom binding via JS if I were running locally, but is there a setting to override <kbd>CTRL+S</kbd> behaviour - especially when a function node edit pane is open?

Answer (score 3):

The default keyboard shortcut to confirm the edit dialog is `Ctrl-Enter`

You can change that under the keyboard shortcuts options of the settings dialog.

Comment: This is the answer to my question. It lead me to the whole Keyboard bindings section under: User Settings > Keyboard. In turn, I found that a binding was not defined for the `Deploy` button click. I clicked-to-edit that option and entered: `cntrl-shift-enter` (all spelled out like that) and now it's so nice to edit then: `cntrl-enter` to close the edit pane, followed by `cntrl-shift-enter` to deploy changes! So nice!

Comment: Also very handy is the "Show User Settings" shortcut: `cntrl-,` (not toggle, but open).